# ARM KeyVault Access Policies Conditional Add

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to add an access policy via a conditional statement? Basically, if environment == production I don't want to add the registration.

I have the following in my template however I don't want the application called `foobarApplicationId` to be added if the environment is production. Can I do this inline or do I need a seperate template? Will setting `foobarApplicationId` to be an empty string work?

```
    {
      "name": "[variables('keyVault-name')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "sku": {
          "family": "A",
          "name": "standard"
        },
        "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[parameters('keyVaultOwner')]",
            "permissions": {
              "keys": [
                "all"
              ],
              "secrets": [
                "all"
              ],
              "certificates": [
                "all"
              ],
              "storage": [
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[parameters('foobarApplicationId')]",
            "permissions": {
              "keys": [
                "get",
                "wrapKey",
                "unwrapKey",
                "sign",
                "verify",
                "list"
              ],
              "secrets": [
                "get",
                "list"
              ],
              "certificates": [
                "get",
                "list"
              ],
              "storage": [
              ]
            }
          },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be in the individual access policy adding a condition section that will take an environment parameter like:

```
 {
        "condition": "[not(equals(parameters('environment'),'PROD'))]"
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "objectId": "[parameters('foobarApplicationId')]",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "get",
            "wrapKey",
            "unwrapKey",
            "sign",
            "verify",
            "list"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "get",
            "list"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "get",
            "list"
          ],
          "storage": [
          ]
        }
      }
```

Comment: How are you trying to add it?

Comment: I was adding it as `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies`. I needed to add policies depending on the env. I ended up just conditionally deploying the ARM template itself.

Comment: Does this work? I can't find any documentation on using the condition key in an access policy object

Comment: Yes, the condition deployment is a feature on any azure resource via ARM https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/conditional-resource-deployment it will skip the resource if the condition isn't met.

Comment: But you have the "condition" key in the actual access policy object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/accesspolicies), not the resource object. The link you provided only talks about the resource.

Comment: I tried this approach and it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

`"condition"` within `"accessPolicies"` doesn't seem to have any effect for me. It doesn't cause any validation or deployment error, but the access policies got added even when the condition evaluated to false.

I found the following trick works better: Use an `if` clause for your `"objectId"` and `"permissions"`, such that if the condition is false, you would assign an empty set of permissions to the empty GUID, effectively becoming a no-op.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",

  "variables": {
    "keyVaultNoPermissions": { },
    "keyVaultAppReadPermissions": {
      "keys": [ "get", "wrapKey", "unwrapKey", "sign", "verify", "list" ],
      "secrets": [ "get", "list" ],
      "certificates": [ "get", "list" ]
    }
  },

  "resources": [
    // ...
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
      "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/add')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('keyVaultName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[if(not(equals(parameters('environment'), 'PROD')), parameters('foobarApplicationId'), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')]",
            "permissions": "[if(not(equals(parameters('environment'), 'PROD')), variables('keyVaultAppReadPermissions'), variables('keyVaultNoPermissions'))]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Since your resource is only the addition of a single access policy, you would be better off putting your condition on the resource itself, so that it will simply not run if the condition evaluates to false. As it is you are working very hard to add empty permissions to an identity that probably doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Add the access policies separately, conditionally. You can see an explanation [here](https://www.unravelled.dev/azure-arm-templates-conditionally-add-an-access-policy-to-a-key-vault/).

```json
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[variables('keyVault-name')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "sku": {
          "family": "A",
          "name": "standard"
        },
        "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[parameters('keyVaultOwner')]",
            "permissions": {
              "keys": [
                "all"
              ],
              "secrets": [
                "all"
              ],
              "certificates": [
                "all"
              ],
              "storage": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[concat(variables('keyVault-name'), '/add')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
      "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
      "condition": "[not(startsWith(parameters('environmentName'), 'PROD'))]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "sku": {
          "family": "A",
          "name": "standard"
        },
        "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[parameters('foobarApplicationId')]",
            "permissions": {
              "keys": [
                "get",
                "wrapKey",
                "unwrapKey",
                "sign",
                "verify",
                "list"
              ],
              "secrets": [
                "get",
                "list"
              ],
              "certificates": [
                "get",
                "list"
              ],
              "storage": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```